# Load a CSV file into a DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, csv, datatable

I'm having a go at moving one of our simpler apps to Silverlight (a bit of a learning exercise). I've quickly come unstuck as I can't figure out how to load (or bind maybe?) a csv file to a datagrid (i.e. so you can point the app at a local csv file and display it to the user). I do have boilerplate code to parse a csv file and return a datatable but I'm shocked to discover that Silverlight doesn't even support DataTable (wtf!).

Any ideas at all how to do this? How do people bind data to a datagrid anyhow?

I'm using Silverlight 3.0 included in VS2010.

Comment: You may wish to include the version of Silverlight you're using.

Comment: Well it seems from doing a bit more reading that DataGrid accepts a list object as a "datasource", and this list could hold a class that exposes properties for each column in the datagrid. The problem here is that this wouldn't work with a CSV file for which could be 1 column or 100+ columns wide...

Comment: I then thought I could maybe create a list containing string[], but of course the datagrid ends up binding to the properties of string (Length, Rank, IsReadOnly etc.) arggh!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Christ finally got it working (might be a bit kludgy tho). So in the end I used the CSVReader (not my code, nicked from someone ages ago):

http://pastebin.com/f56674dfb

and then I adapted some code from this excellent idea:

http://blog.bodurov.com/blog/Post.aspx?postID=27

mashing it all together and eventually coming up with:

http://pastebin.com/fb64198e

Thankyouverymuch!

In the end I adapted the CSV reader to use this excelent [datatable](http://slbindabledatagrid.codeplex.com/) class

Comment: As a suggestion, consider moving that CVS reader code out of your code-behind.  It really doesn't belong there.  It should be its own class for several reasons.

Comment: I found this more simple for dynamically creating the columns http://slbindabledatagrid.codeplex.com/ compared to Vladimir Bodurov's example you gave.

Comment: Yes you are right - in the end I would use the slbindabledatagrid rather than the Bodurov solution